# isomorphism of tensor product of von Neumann algebras

Tags: tensor-products, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M_i(i=1,2)$ and $N_i(i=1,2)$ be von Neumann algebras. If $M_i\cong N_i(i=1,2)$, then we have
$\mathcal{M}_1\overline\otimes\mathcal{M}_2\cong   \mathcal{N}_1\overline\otimes\mathcal{N}_2$.

If $\mathcal{M}_1\overline\otimes\mathcal{M}_2\cong   \mathcal{N}_1\overline\otimes\mathcal{N}_2$, can we conclude that
$M_i\cong N_i(i=1,2)$?  If the conclusion is not correct, can anyone show me a counterexample, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously this is false. Surely, if the analogue fails for finite-dimensional vector spaces, you wouldn't expect to hold it in another setting right?

Take $M \ne N$. Then $M \overline{\otimes} N \cong N \overline{\otimes} M$, the isomorphism being implemented by a unitary on the underlying Hilbert spaces.

If you don't like this example, think finite-dimensional (where the von Neumann-tensor product coincides with the usual tensor product):

$$\mathbb{C}^2\overline{\otimes}\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{C}^4 \overline{\otimes}\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}^4.$$